# Ocelot gatway doesn't work with selected port

Tags: c#, asp.net, ocelot

I want to use ocelot middleware with full dns address.
But If I sent request to selected port postman says ECONNREFUSED.
If I change the port it doesn't help me.
I added ocelot.json and ocelot.developments.json file but it also doesn't help me.
Note that I added to Routes directory two ocelot.some-api.json and ocelot.SwaggerEndPoint.json files.
You can see the ocelot.json file below:

```
{
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5544"
  },
  "Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gw/token",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v2/users/get-token",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "some-selected-address.az"
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "SwaggerKey": "biosign"
    }
  ],
  "SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "biosign",
      "TransformByOcelotConfig": true,
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "Biosign API",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "http://some-selected-address.az/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The Program.cs is:

```
using gateway_api.Config;
using MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowed((hosts) => true));
});

string routesDirectory = "Routes";
builder.Configuration.AddOcelotWithSwaggerSupport(options => { options.Folder = routesDirectory; });
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => 
{
    options.ResolveConflictingActions(p => p.FirstOrDefault());
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
}
#region Remove in future
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
#endregion

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(options => 
{ 
    options.PathToSwaggerGenerator = "/swagger/docs";
    options.ReConfigureUpstreamSwaggerJson = AlterUpstream.AlterUpstreamSwaggerJson;
});

app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.MapControllers();

//app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");


app.Run();
```